# My Java Spring JPA query is not returning what the equivalent MySQL query is returning

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am using Java Spring for a web service I am working on. There is a query that I am having trouble getting to work.

In MySQL Workbench, this bit of query works fine:

```
SELECT * from Employees e
WHERE e.personnel_type like 'Full Time'
AND e.branch like '%%'
AND e.office like '%%'
```

Notice the `branch` and `office` are empty, not supplied.

If I run this query in MySQL, I get all employees that are "Full Time", regardless of the `branch` or `office`.

However, in my JPA query:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
    @Query("
    FROM Employees e
    WHERE e.personnelType like :personnelType
    AND e.branch like %:branch%
    AND e.officelike %:office%
    ");
    List<Object[]> employeeSearch(
        @Param("personnelType") String personnelType,
        @Param("branch") String branch,
        @Param("office") String office
    );
```

If I do not supply the `branch` or `office`, I get nothing; it's like the wildcard `%%` is not working.

However, if I do supply the `branch` and `office`, I get the records I am supposed to.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: When you say "do not supply" what is the value of branch and office null or empty ? My guess would be your query is like this " AND e.branch like %null%  "

Comment: You are 100% correct. I just double-checked my code and I am sending a `null` and not an empty `String`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you do the following, you can pass null as well and it will work

```
    FROM Employees e
    WHERE e.personnelType like :personnelType
    AND (:branch is null OR e.branch like %:branch%)
    AND (:office is null OR e.officelike %:office%)
```

Answer (score 0):

First change/optimize you MySQL query to this

> SELECT * from Employees e
> WHERE e.personnel_type = 'Full Time'

it will return the same result as the one you wrote

- why to use **like** if you will not use any wildcards
- why to use **like '%'**, if you will not use a criteria like this on that column it will "by default" get them all, because you have not specified any restrictions on them

So after changing the query to

> SELECT * from Employees e
> WHERE e.personnel_type = 'Full Time'

your query will work much faster and you will be able to write method instead of writing a JPA Query. And this method will simply look like this

> List<Object[]> findAllEmployeesByName(String name)

**NOTE:**I also guess that your persistence  is not well constructed because of **Object[]** type for **Employees** Entity. I would advice you to rethink that.